# ASIHTTPRequest issues for the iPHone

Tags: iphone, asihttprequest

I have a buddy who is building the web server side of things and he
needs my iphone app to send him a request.  I don't have any
experience in this type of programming so it is proving to be a bit
difficult.

I am trying to do a simple request that looks like this:

```
        ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:
[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://thewebserverURL"]];
        [request setPostValue:[NSString stringWithCString:txtName
encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] forKey:@"field02"];
        [request setPostValue:[NSString stringWithCString:txtTodaysDate
encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] forKey:@"field05"];
        [request startSynchronous];
        NSLog(@"%@",[request responseString]);
```

I am getting 2 errors on each of the "request setPostValue" lines that
read "Passing argument 1 of stringWithCString: encoding from
incompatible pointer type."

txtName and txtTodaysDate are both NSStrings.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `setPostValue` parameter is supposed to be a `NSString`, so you can just pass `txtName` and `txtTodaysDate` directly.  `stringWithCString` is used for converting a NUL-terminated C string to a NSString.  Thus, the first parameter is a `char *`.